# Firebug: "invalid regular expression flag h" after running YUI Compressor

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, validation, yui-compressor

After I run YUI Compressor, I'm getting this error:

```
invalid regular expression flag h
[Break On This Error] ction(event){$(this).removeClass('lumi...cs_glb.php</b> on line <b>221</b><br/>
```

The part of the JS code in questions is:

```
//Form LUMI
$('input').focus(function(event){
    $(this).addClass('lumi');
});

$('input').blur(function(event){
    $(this).removeClass('lumi');
});
```

I validated the JS code with http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php and it points no error.

Does anybody knows what's wrong?

Comment: What does the YUICompressor *output* look like?

Comment: Also, are you getting that error *from* YUICompressor, or are you getting it from the browser?

Comment: I am getting the error from Firebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying one thousand ways to debug this, I found out that a php warning was causing the error. It is hard to find this kind of error because the Firebug debugger was pointing to a totally different direction. Thanks.